# Passing url parameters to Firefox but open urls in new windows, not tabs

Tags: windows, command-line, script, firefox, url

I want to open around 10 instances of firefox using the command line like

```
firefox.exe www.google.com www.msn.com www.yahoo.com
```

But by default, firefox opens these web pages in tabs, i want firefox to open them in seperate windows.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the `-new-window`*`URL`* parameter to Firefox will open the URL in a new window. I haven't tested it, but it would make sense that either:

1. You could pass multiple URLs after the `-new-window` option, or,
2. You could use multiple `-new-window` operators in sequence (e.g. `firefox.exe -new-window google.ca -new-window example.org`).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the various command line options for opening a URL in a new tab or window @ [Mozilla's developer command line options page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/command_line_options).